# Handling textbox .change when using JQuery UI Autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, switch-statement

I have a search box with a JQuery UI autocomplete function. I want the terms entered by the user to be compared against a set of cases (see "kittens" and "puppies" in the switch statement below. See also the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XcbMQ/4/).

This existing code works IF the user types the entire word "kittens":

```
  $('#change').text("nothing entered yet")

 var $typeahead = new Array ("kittens","puppies","giraffe","trucks");

 $('#query').autocomplete({source: $typeahead, autoFocus: true}).change(function() {   
 var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
 switch (text) {
     case "kittens":
         $('#change').text("kittens");
         break;
     case "puppies":
         $('#change').text("puppies");
         break;
     default:
         $('#change').text("neither kittens nor puppies");    
         break;
 }
 });
```

But if the user takes advantage of the autocomplete and arrows down to select option "kittens" after typing only a few letters, then nothing happens- because my function is bound to .change, and when .change is triggered on #query, there is not yet a match. IE the user has entered "ki" and then arrowed down, and this does not match "kittens".

How can I change my function so that it isn't triggered until the whole word has been entered, either by the user manually typing "kittens", OR by the user typing "ki" and then selecting from the autocomplete options? To put it another way: what options exist other than .change to detect that an entry has been made in the text box?

Answer (score 0):

.blur is the key- trigger actions when the text box loses focus. This means a user can either type in the whole word "kitten", or begin scrolling down the autocorrect list, and that will trigger my function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/blur#fn